# Changing hover text on a button?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a button and I hover over it and get some text, for example, 'unclicked'. Then, I click on it. Now, when I hover over it, I should get the message, 'user_1 clicked on the button". If someone else navigates to the same page and clicks on the button, it would then read "user_2 clicked on the button" and so on. Anyone have any tips on how to do this?

I tried setting a title = "unclicked" as the default, and I have an onclick which has elem = document.getElementById(name).title = "clicked by", user, but that doesn't do anything. I then tried associating a method with title=, but I think that only accepts strings because when I tried, hovering only displayed the method name.

Comment: I tried setting a title = "unclicked" as the default, and I have an onclick which has elem = document.getElementById(name).title = "clicked by", user, but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: There's too little here to begin to help without offering a complete solution that you would have had no part in. What does your HTML button code look like? How does your javascript interact with it? Where are you storing which user pressed it last?

Comment: @Dharman Oh man, I haven't seen that article in years :-D

Comment: @Dharman: please be careful with comments of that style and, ideally, provide context (why are you asking?) and guidance (how to share previous attempts). Further, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require more than just client-side code, you'll need to actively store the last click in a data store and retrieve it each time. A quick psuedo'd example:

```
//Clicking the button will make an AJAX call to the server and store the user that clicked
$("button").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       ..
       ..
    });
}).hover(function() {
    //Hovering will run an AJAX call and get the last user that clicked
    $.ajax({
       ..
       ..
    })
});
```